# Query with eloquent or Where clause

Tags: laravel

This query return me not the right values .

everything is going well till $query->where('valid_licence_id', '1') but when i add :

->where('statut_licence_id' , '4')
                ->orWhere('statut_licence_id' , '1');

the query display me the result with 'valid_licence_id = 3 and not 1 . someone now here i'm doing wrong ? thanks a lot in advance

```
$licencies = Licencies::where(['structure_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
                ->where('statut_licence_id' , '4')
                ->orWhere('statut_licence_id' , '1');
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
        return view('licencie/notConfirmed', compact('licencies'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this

```
->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
```

Out of the closure.

```
->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('statut_licence_id' , '4')
    ->orWhere('statut_licence_id' , '1');
})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Hi @MathieuMourareau I am glad I helped. Please, don't forget to mark my answer. Thanks :)